# How to Spawn a parameterised thread which will return a Boolean value in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am trying to call a method which will return me Boolean values(-1,0,1) by invoking a thread  something like:

```
public void CreateThread()
{
    ThreadStart ts =delegate{check(55);};

    Thread tUpdateNow = new Thread(ts);

    tUpdateNow.Start();

//According to the return value perform some task.
}   
public bool check(int n)
{    
    if(n%2==0)
        return 1;

    else if(n%2>=0)
        return 0;

    else
        return -1;    
}
```

But I don't know how to implement this using C#. Anybody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend working with [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for something like this. You can subscribe to events that will fire when the thread completes. See: [BackgroundWorker Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker_events.aspx).

Something like:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

You can store the result of the `DoWork` method in the `DoWorkEventArgs` Result property. When the `RunWorkerCompleted` event fires, you can retrieve this result from the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` Result property.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Task Parallel Library which wraps all this for you.

```
Task<bool> task = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => check(55));
bool result = task.Result;
```

Comment: can you please give me some idea about Task class, like some example

Comment: What do you mean? The System.Threading.Tasks.Task class is part of the Task Parallel Library which is included in .Net 4.0. You can find the basics of this library here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Actually while I am implementing it in my application its saying an error "The type or namespace name Tasks is not exist in the namespace "System.Threading " so for that purpose I asked this

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadStart` returns void, so in your delegate you are calling your check method and it is throwing away the return value. You will need to store that value somewhere else and then check it once the thread has completed.